# Solving quintic in radicals

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, special-functions, polynomials

I need to find an explicit expression in radicals for the real root of the quintic equation

```
1152921504606846976 + 99923616732282880 x + 3740744716124160 x^2 - 2794496983040 x^3 + 2257838080 x^4 + x^5 == 0
```

I tried to use [Radicals.nb](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/TechNotes/158/Radical.nb?file_id=41) from [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/TechNotes/158). `SolvableQ` says the equation is solvable in radicals, but `SolveQuintic` returns `$Failed` for some reason. Could you please help me to find an explicit solution, and suggest how to fix this apparent bug in `SolveQuintic`?

The quintic equation is not completely random, its real root is actually the value of

```
With[{q = -Exp[-π √47]}, QPochhammer[q, q^2]^24/q]]
```

and should have an explicit representation in radicals.

Comment: Were you at least able to perform a Tschirnhaus transformation on it?

Comment: I tried to perform it using function from [TschirnhausTransformation.nb](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/TechNotes/158/TschirnhausTransformation.nb?file_id=43), but it looks _Mathematica_ chokes on too large expressions.

Comment: Could try code from [this Wolfram Communiity post](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/980264).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Isn't that post about radical denesting? How do I apply it to solving quintics?

Comment: Yes, it is about denesting. I guess I had a hope that it might be able to go from min poly to radical expression.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I wrote this function based on Daniel Lazard's paper [*Solving Quintics by Radicals*](http://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-18908-1_6):

```
QuinticToRadicals[root_Root] := 
  Block[{a, b, c, d, e, f, h, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, z, g, F, A, 
    B, G, H, L, M, P, Q, R, S},
   If[!TrueQ[Element[root, Algebraics]], Return[root]];
   With[{m = MinimalPolynomial[root, z]},
    If[!PolynomialQ[m, z] || Exponent[m, z] != 5, 
     Return[root]];
    {f, e, d, c, b, a} = CoefficientList[m, z]];
   p = (5 a c - 2 b^2)/(5 a^2);
   q = (25 a^2 d - 15 a b c + 4 b^3)/(25 a^3);
   r = (125 a^3 e - 50 a^2 b d + 15 a b^2 c - 3 b^4)/(125 a^4);
   s = (3125 a^4 f - 625 a^3 b e + 125 a^2 b^2 d - 25 a b^3 c + 4 b^5)/(3125 a^5);
   G = Select[Solve[{(p^2 + 12 r + 4 t) Discriminant[z^5 + p z^3 + q z^2 + r z + s, z] 
     == (2 t^3 + 8 t^2 r + (2 p q^2 - 6 p^2 r + 24 r^2 - 50 q s) t - 2 q^4 + 
         13 p q^2 r - 16 (p^2 - 4 r) r^2 - 5 q (3 p^2 + 40 r) s + 
         125 p s^2)^2, 
     4 r^2 + 2 q (p q + 5 s + 2 u) + 5 x == 
      t^2 + 2 p^2 (3 r + t) + 2 p v, 
     3 p^4 (2 r + t) + 5 p s (50 s + 9 u) + 
       3 q^2 (18 p r + 5 p t + 4 v) + 
       q (-20 s (7 r + 3 t) + 6 r u + p w) + 
       2 (40 r^3 + 16 r^2 t + t^3 + 25 s w + 10 r x) == 
      14 q^4 + 28 p r v + 
       p^2 (52 r^2 + 36 r t + q (3 p q + 41 s + 3 u) - 3 p v + 3 x), 
     q^4 (30 r - 4 t) + t^4 + p^4 (22 r^2 - 6 q s + 4 r t) + 
       q^2 (50 s^2 - 155 s u - 29 r v) + 
       p^3 (-4 q^2 (4 r + t) + 9 s u + 4 r v) + 
       p (q^3 (-132 s + 8 u) - 5 s (110 r s - 5 s t + 28 r u) + 
          16 r^2 v + q (105 s v + 8 r w) - 
          3 q^2 (14 r^2 + 5 r t - 3 x)) + 
       p^2 (4 q^4 - 68 r^3 + 16 r^2 t + 
          q (404 r s + 79 s t - 17 r u) - 4 q^2 v - 15 s w - 
          19 r x) == 
      16 r^4 + 3 q^3 w + 20 r s (4 q t + 5 w) + 
       4 r^2 (5 q s - 17 q u - 15 x) + 25 s (5 s v + 9 q x), 
     625 s^3 (10 s + u) + q^5 (858 s + 20 u) + 
       p^5 (198 s^2 + 5 q^2 (5 r + t) - 15 r v) + 
       q^2 (5 s (2140 r s + 365 s t + 43 r u) - 12 r^2 v) + 
       q^4 (-34 r^2 - 43 r t + 22 x) + 
       8 r^2 (120 r^3 + 64 r^2 t + 25 s w + 30 r x) + 
       p^3 (q^3 (181 s - 5 u) + s (-810 r s + 355 s t - 147 r u) + 
          168 r^2 v - q (212 s v + 11 r w) - 
          q^2 (22 r (13 r + 5 t) + 5 x)) + 
       p^4 (-5 q^4 + q (-491 r s - 200 s t + 15 r u) + 5 q^2 v + 
          18 s w + r (4 r (91 r + 50 t) + 15 x)) + 
       p^2 (5 q^4 (19 r + 3 t) + 
          2 q r (2060 r s + 864 s t - 45 r u) + 325 s^2 v + 
          q^2 (3005 s^2 + 351 s u - 83 r v) + 3 q^3 w + 290 q s x - 
          2 r (544 r^3 + 216 r^2 t + 265 s w + 76 r x)) == 
      15 p^6 r (2 r + t) + 2 (t^5 + 750 r s^2 v) + 
       q^3 (620 s v + 41 r w) + 
       q (2640 r^2 s t + 8 r^3 (780 s - 19 u) + 2375 s^2 w + 
          700 r s x) + 
       p (12 q^6 + 20 r s (-45 r s + 10 s t + 21 r u) + 
          q^3 (4095 r s + 752 s t + 43 r u) - 10 q^4 v + 176 r^3 v + 
          5 q s (635 s (5 s + u) - 312 r v) - 124 q r^2 w + 
          1375 s^2 x - q^2 (612 r^3 + 220 r^2 t + 110 s w - 27 r x)), 
     Element[t, Rationals]}, {t, u, v, w, x}], FreeQ[ConditionalExpression], 1];
   If[G == {}, Return[root], G /. Rule -> Set];
   g = -3 p^2 (-v + q^2) + 20 v r - 50 u s + 125 s^2 + 
     3 q^2 (-7 r + t) + p^3 (4 r + 3 t) + 
     p (16 r^2 - q (u - 40 s) + 12 r t);
   h = 366 v q^3 - 402 q^5 - 748 u q^2 r + 440 w r^2 - 448 q r^3 - 
     12 p^5 s - 275 w q s + 2100 v r s - 1925 q^2 r s - 4875 u s^2 - 
     1875 s^3 + x (-65 p^2 q - 550 q r + 875 p s) + 524 q r^2 t - 
     1040 q^2 s t + p^4 q (158 r + 85 t) + 
     p^3 (85 v q - 85 q^3 + 4 u r - 1462 r s - 418 s t) + 
     p (41 w q^2 - 298 v q r - 56 u r^2 + 5 q s (419 u + 35 s) + 
        10 r s (290 r + 159 t) + q^3 (896 r + 419 t)) - 
     p^2 (58 w r + 520 v s + q (73 u q - 142 r^2 + 159 q s + 440 r t));
   F = Sqrt[
    5 (40 x p - 120 w q + p^2 (-24 v + 40 q^2) + 100 v r + 
       332 q^2 r - 300 u s + 125 s^2 + p^3 (-80 r - 24 t) + 24 q^2 t +
        p (88 u q + 160 r^2 - 480 q s + 100 r t))]; 
   A = Sqrt[5/2 (g + h/F)]; 
   B = 1/(A F)
      5 (42 q^5 + 12 p^5 s + 3 p^4 q (14 r + 5 t) + 
       q^2 (550 r s + 515 s t - 182 r u) - 6 q^3 v + 
       p^3 (-15 q^3 + 492 r s + 213 s t - 4 r u + 15 q v) - 
       50 s (25 s^2 - 60 s u + 22 r v) - 40 r^2 w + 650 q s w + 
       p^2 (-3 q^2 (52 s + 9 u) + 195 s v - 22 r w + 
          q (358 r^2 + 50 r t - 35 x)) - 
       8 q r (29 r^2 + 23 r t + 25 x) + 
       p (q^3 (-246 r + t) + 5 q s (565 s - 54 u) - 
          4 r (350 r s + 235 s t - 24 r u) + 68 q r v + 19 q^2 w - 
          250 s x));
   H = -1750 w q + p^2 (-600 v + 500 q^2) + 2500 v r - 7500 u s + 
     3125 s^2 + q^2 (-700 r - 1150 t) + p^3 (-2000 r - 600 t) + 
     p (1000 x + 1700 u q + 4000 r^2 - 6375 q s + 2500 r t); 
   L = -25 x p - 9 v p^2 - 25 w q - 7 u p q - 7 p^2 q^2 - 60 v r + 
     50 p^3 r + 128 q^2 r - 308 p r^2 + 525 u s - 145 p q s - 
     1000 s^2 - p^3 t + 11 q^2 t - 96 p r t; 
   M = -125 x p + 67 v p^2 + 75 w q - 109 u p q - 79 p^2 q^2 - 
     420 v r + 210 p^3 r + 496 q^2 r - 676 p r^2 + 1175 u s - 
     415 p q s - 750 s^2 + 63 p^3 t + 27 q^2 t - 412 p r t; {A, B, 
     F} = Select[{{A, B, F}, {-A, -B, F}, {B, -A, -F}, {-B, A, -F}}, 
      Apply[25 (2 u - p q - 5 s) + (L #1 + M #2)/g + H/#3 != 0 &], 
      1][[1]];
   
   P = 1/5 (5/4 (25 (2 u - p q - 5 s) + (L A + M B)/g + H/F))^(1/5); 
   Q = -((4 p^2 q + 2 (36 q r + 7 q t - 5 w) + p (-45 s + 4 u + F))/(
     10 P F)); 
   R = 1/(500 P^2) (-25 q + (
       25 (-40 r^2 - 35 q s + 2 p^2 (10 r + t) - 22 q u + 
          2 p (q^2 + v) - 10 x))/F + 
       1/g 2 (-105 q s A - 140 q s B + 4 r t (3 A + 4 B) + 
          2 p q^2 (7 A + 11 B) + r^2 (76 A + 68 B) - 
          2 p^2 (29 r A + 3 A t + 17 r B + 9 t B) + 23 q A u + 
          14 q B u - 2 p (2 A + 11 B) v + 35 A x + 5 B x)); 
   S = 1/(500 P^3) (1/
        g (-80 r s A + 30 s A t + 60 r s B + 40 s t B + 
          14 q^3 (A + 3 B) - 16 r g + 3 t g + 
          2 p^2 (26 s A + 18 s B + g) + 8 r A u + 44 r B u - 
          2 q (p (26 r A + 3 A t + 33 r B + 14 t B) + (A + 18 B) v) + 
          p (-8 A w + 6 B w)) + (
       5 (8 p^3 q - 2 p q (13 r + t) + p^2 (-20 s + 8 u) + 
          5 (14 q^3 + 10 r s - 5 s t - 10 r u - 2 q v)))/F); 
   Select[{P + Q + R + 
        S, (-1)^(4/5) P - (-1)^(1/5) Q + (-1)^(2/5) R - (-1)^(3/5)
          S, -(-1)^(3/5) P + (-1)^(2/5) Q + (-1)^(4/5) R - (-1)^(1/5)
          S, +(-1)^(2/5) P - (-1)^(3/5) Q - (-1)^(1/5) R + (-1)^(4/5)
          S, -(-1)^(1/5) P + (-1)^(4/5) Q - (-1)^(3/5) R + (-1)^(2/5)
          S} - b/(5 a), !TrueQ[# != root] &, 1][[1]]];
```

**Beware!** If found some typos in the paper on p. 222 in the formula for $P_{22}$: the term $\color{red}{8p^3}$ should be replaced with $8p^3q$, and the term $\color{red}{70q^3q}$ should be replaced with $70q^3$.

The function can be used on quintic `Root` objects as follows:

```
QuinticToRadicals[Root[-1 + 2 #1 + 3 #1^2 + #1^5 &, 1]]
```

---

After some simplifications the root I am interested in can be represented as

```
Block[{a, b, c, d, f, g, h}, 
  a = Sqrt[25778705 + 5353862 Sqrt[5]]; 
  b = 253 Sqrt[47] Sqrt[223185962057628283872014741096225 + 
     46404398781233715250377772758698 Sqrt[5]]; 
  c = 118179607126755427283 - 33773932059671 Sqrt[5]; 
  d = 1302883789494160617301390 - 930862886277288987 Sqrt[5]; 
  f = 765881115 - 1071962031710725 Sqrt[5]; 
  g = 5155741^(1/5) (6514418947470803086506950 - 4654314431386444935 Sqrt[5] + 
      253 Sqrt[47] Sqrt[223185962057628283872014741096225 + 
        46404398781233715250377772758698 Sqrt[5]])^(1/5); 
  h = 1/(5 d + b)^(1/5); 
   -1024/25778705 (10 5^(1/5) 10311482^(4/5) g + 
      253 10^(2/5) Sqrt[47]
        a h^2 (4993350841 5^(1/5) + 825542539482355 2^(1/5) h) + (
      38747022105 Sqrt[47] (-831611761 5^(1/10) 10311482^(2/5) + 
         18363423328399 2^(3/5) 5^(9/10) g^2 h^3))/(a g^2) + 
      25778705 (440984 + 2 2^(4/5) 5^(1/5) (5 d - b)^(1/5) - 
         2^(2/5) 5^(1/10) h^2 (f - 2^(1/5) 5^(3/10) c h)))]
```

---

*Update*: I found a rather simple case case when my implementation fails:

```
QuinticToRadicals[Root[-6 - 10 #1 - 10 #1^2 + #1^5 &, 1]]
```

gives a message about division by zero and returns `Indeterminate`, while the expected answer is

```
2^(1/5) + 2^(2/5)
```

It will try to investigate and fix this issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please let me know if you find solvable quintics that this program cannot handle.

Comment: How to use it?..

Comment: @Anixx `QuinticToRadicals[Root[-1 + 2 #1 + 3 #1^2 + #1^5 &, 1]]`

Comment: Thank you! I tried this before but it did not work for some reason.

Comment: What happens if you remove all the conditional checks? Will it produce incorrect results?

Comment: Something will break down. The line `{f, e, d, c, b, a} = CoefficientList[m, z]` assumes there are 6 coefficients. If you provide something other than a quintic, you will get an error "Set::shape: Lists {…} and {…} are not the same shape." You can try to do it.

Comment: Well, I removed the checks other than that for the order of input. What I get for non-solvable quintics are expressions with various Root objects of 6th order.

Comment: I hoped I would get expressions, maybe, in other special functions... Wikipedia says there was a general formula (for solvable quintics), on 3 pages, but the linked .ps file does not open.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20050106213422if_/http://www.loria.fr/serveurs/publications/2002/A02-R-449/A02-R-449.ps

Comment: The algorithm was designed to work correctly with solvable quintics only. If you remove the checks and feed something else to it, the behavior is totally undefined. You should not assume that the results it returns in those cases make any sense.

Comment: It would be great if you could amend your function with the method by Tyma Gaidash who found how to solve a general quintic in terms of InverseBetaRegularized function https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4442541/2513

Comment: For `QuinticToRadicals[Root[-1 + 2 #1 + 3 #1^2 + #1^5 &, 1]]` your formula gives a very big output, while a shorter answer is  $-\frac{\sqrt[5]{91 \sqrt{5}-\sqrt{\frac{94}{5} \left(4225-\frac{9439}{\sqrt{5}}\right)}-195}}{2^{2/5} 5^{3/5}}-\frac{\sqrt[5]{91 \sqrt{5}+\sqrt{\frac{94}{5} \left(4225-\frac{9439}{\sqrt{5}}\right)}-195}}{2^{2/5} 5^{3/5}}-\frac{\sqrt[5]{50 \sqrt{\frac{7943}{6250}+\frac{443633}{156250 \sqrt{5}}}-\frac{91}{\sqrt{5}}-39}}{10^{2/5}}-\frac{(-1)^{4/5} \sqrt[5]{-50 \sqrt{\frac{7943}{6250}+\frac{443633}{156250 \sqrt{5}}}-\frac{91}{\sqrt{5}}-39}}{10^{2/5}}$

Comment: Or even $-\frac{(-1)^{4/5} \sqrt[5]{-455 \sqrt{5}-\sqrt{94 \left(9439 \sqrt{5}+21125\right)}-975}+\sqrt[5]{-455 \sqrt{5}+\sqrt{94 \left(9439 \sqrt{5}+21125\right)}-975}+\sqrt[5]{455 \sqrt{5}-\sqrt{94 \left(21125-9439 \sqrt{5}\right)}-975}+\sqrt[5]{455 \sqrt{5}+\sqrt{94 \left(21125-9439 \sqrt{5}\right)}-975}}{2^{2/5} 5^{4/5}}$

Comment: @Anixx "the linked .ps file does not open." That is because really it is a tar file. You need to rename to tar and then unarchive and then open in Adobe distiller.

Comment: Here is a PDF version: https://hal.science/hal-02547734/file/lip6.1998.023.pdf, https://web.archive.org/web/20230420232658id_/https://hal.science/hal-02547734/file/lip6.1998.023.pdf (I found it in comments here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3918945/19661)

Answer (score 10):

I reproduced the algorithm from this post and I tried to use it on your example: [An Easy Way To Solve The Solvable Quintic Using Two Sextics](http://www.oocities.org/titus_piezas/Quintic.pdf).

As mentioned in the article, for the quintic equation:

$$a x^5 + b x^4 + c x^3 + d x^2 + e x + f=0$$

If the equation is solvable, then the solution is of the form:

$$\begin{bmatrix} x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\\x_5 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ e^{+\frac{2 i \pi }{5}} & e^{+\frac{4 i \pi }{5}} & e^{-\frac{4 i \pi}{5}} & e^{-\frac{2 i \pi}{5}} \\ e^{+\frac{4 i \pi }{5}} & e^{-\frac{2 i \pi}{5}} & e^{+\frac{2 i \pi }{5}} & e^{-\frac{4 i \pi}{5}} \\ e^{-\frac{4 i \pi}{5}} & e^{+\frac{2 i \pi }{5}} & e^{-\frac{2 i \pi}{5}} & e^{+\frac{4 i \pi }{5}} \\ e^{-\frac{2 i \pi}{5}} & e^{-\frac{4 i \pi}{5}} & e^{+\frac{4 i \pi }{5}} & e^{+\frac{2 i \pi }{5}} \\ \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt[5]{\zeta_1}\\ \sqrt[5]{\zeta_2}\\ \sqrt[5]{\zeta_3}\\ \sqrt[5]{\zeta_4}\\ \end{bmatrix}-\frac{b}{5a}$$

So my algorithm only gives $\zeta_1,\zeta_2,\zeta_3,\zeta_4$.

```
simplify[e_] := FullSimplify[
    ToRadicals@e,
    ComplexityFunction -> (100 Count[#, Root[__], All] + LeafCount[#]&)
];
getCoefficient[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_] := {
    (-2 b^2 + 5 a c) / (50 a^2),
    (4 b^3 - 15 a b c + 25 a^2 d) / (250 a^3),
    (-3 b^4 + 15 a b^2 c - 50 a^2 b d + 125 a^3 e) / (625 a^4),
    (b (4 b^4 - 25 a b^2 c + 125 a^2 b d - 625 a^3 e)) / (3125 a^5) + f / a
};
findGenerator[a_, b_, c_, d_] := Block[
    {\[CapitalDelta], d1, d2, g1, g2, discriminant, generator},
    \[CapitalDelta] = 16 c^2 (-200 a^3 b^2 - 135 b^4 + 400 a^4 c + 360 a b^2 c - 160 a^2 c^2 + 16 c^3) + 32 b (4 b^2 (40 a^3 + 27 b^2) - 45 a (8 a^3 + 7 b^2) c + 140 a^2 c^2 - 20 c^3) d + 8 (432 a^5 + 330 a^2 b^2 - 180 a^3 c + 45 b^2 c + 20 a c^2) d^2 - 120 a b d^3 + d^4;
    d1 = {
        3125,
        0,
        -625 (3 a^2 + c),
        0,
        25 (15 a^4 + 8 a b^2 - 2 a^2 c + 3 c^2 - 2 b d),
        Sqrt[\[CapitalDelta]],
        -25 a^6 - 40 a^3 b^2 - 16 b^4 + 35 a^4 c + 28 a b^2 c - 11 a^2 c^2 + c^3 - 2 b (a^2 + c) d + a d^2
    };
    d2 = {
        3125,
        0,
        625 (-3 b^2 + 4 a c),
        0,
        25 (15 b^4 - 40 a b^2 c + 20 a^2 c^2 - 4 c^3 + 8 a^2 b d + 6 b c d - 2 a d^2),
        d Sqrt[\[CapitalDelta]],
        -25 (b^3 - 2 a b c)^2 - 2 b (20 a^2 - 3 c) (b^2 - 2 a c) d - (16 a^4 + 2 a b^2 - 8 a^2 c + c^2) d^2 + b d^3
    };
    g1 = guessGenerator[d1];
    g2 = guessGenerator[d2];
    If[Length@g1 == 0, Return[Failure["Unable to solve", <||>]]];
    If[Length@g2 == 0, Return[Failure["Unable to solve", <||>]]];
    {First@guessGenerator[d1], First@guessGenerator[d2]}
];
guessGenerator[discriminant_] := Block[
    {kx, ks},
    ks = NSolve[FromDigits[discriminant, kx] == 0, kx,Reals, WorkingPrecision -> 60];
    Select[RootApproximant[kx /. ks, 2], FromDigits[discriminant, #] == 0&]
];
solveResolvent[a_, b_, c_, d_, p_, q_] := Block[
    {D5Resolvent, F5Resolvent, kx, var},
    D5Resolvent = {1, d, 2 a^5 - 5 a^3 c - 4 b^2 c + a (c^2 + 2 b d), -a^5 d, a^10};
    F5Resolvent = {
        p,
        p (d - 20 p q),
        -p (2 a^5 + 2 a^2 b^2 + 20 a^3 p^2 + 10 a p^4 + b^2 (c - 6 p^2)) - 2 b (a^3 + b^2 - a c + 3 a p^2) q + (4 a^2 - c) p q^2 + 2 b q^3, -5 a^6 b p + a^7 q + a^5 (-c + p^2) q + a p^3 (-4 b^3 + 3 c p q - 13 p^3 q + 4 b q^2) + a^3 p (-4 b^3 - 2 c p q + 11 p^3 q + 4 b q^2) + a^2 p^2 (-2 b c p + 9 b p^3 + 6 b^2 q - 6 q^3) + a^4 (3 b c p - 5 b p^3 + b^2 q - q^3) + p^4 (b (-c p + p^3) + b^2 q - q^3),
        p (a^2 - p^2)^5
    };
    If[
        p == 0,
        var /. Solve[FromDigits[D5Resolvent, var] == 0, var],
        var /. Solve[FromDigits[F5Resolvent, var] == 0, var]
    ]
];
getPseudoRoot[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_, f_] := Block[
    {p, q, r, s, g, u, v},
    {p, q, r, s} = getCoefficient[a, b, c, d, e, f];
    g = findGenerator[p, q, r, s];
    If[
        FailureQ@g,
        Return@g,
        {u, v} = g
    ];
    {-b / (5a), solveResolvent[p, q, r, s, u, v]}
];
```

---

```
coeff = Reverse@CoefficientList[-1 + 2 #1 + 3 #1^2 + #1^5 &[x], x];
coeff = Reverse@CoefficientList[-6 - 10 #1 - 10 #1^2 + #1^5 &[x], x];
{a, b} = getPseudoRoot @@ coeff
x1 = Tr@Surd[b, 5] + a
(*x1//RootReduce*)
RootApproximant[x1, 5]
```

It successfully found a root of the equation $x^5-10 x^2-10 x-6=0$ is $x_1=\sqrt[5]{2}+2^{2/5}$.

But it failed in your example.

After research, I found that this is not a problem of the algorithm.

The problem is that `RootApproximant` in `guessGenerator` doesn't fit the huge coefficients well, I don't know how to fix this.

After manual fitting, I found $\{p,q\}=\left\{-58275659776 \sqrt{5},26315474732392120320 \sqrt{5}\right\}$

So we have:

\begin{aligned}
-\frac{x_1}{2048}
&=220492\\
&+
2^{4/5} \sqrt[5]{5 \left(-4654314431386444935 \sqrt{5}+253 \sqrt{47 \left(46404398781233715250377772758698 \sqrt{5}+223185962057628283872014741096225\right)}+6514418947470803086506950\right)}\\
&+2^{4/5} \sqrt[5]{5 \left(-4654314431386444935 \sqrt{5}-253 \sqrt{47 \left(46404398781233715250377772758698 \sqrt{5}+223185962057628283872014741096225\right)}+6514418947470803086506950\right)}\\
&+2^{4/5} \sqrt[5]{5 \left(4654314431386444935 \sqrt{5}+253 \sqrt{47 \left(223185962057628283872014741096225-46404398781233715250377772758698 \sqrt{5}\right)}+6514418947470803086506950\right)}\\
&+2^{4/5} \sqrt[5]{5 \left(4654314431386444935 \sqrt{5}-253 \sqrt{47 \left(223185962057628283872014741096225-46404398781233715250377772758698 \sqrt{5}\right)}+6514418947470803086506950\right)}
\end{aligned}

```
eq = 1152921504606846976 + 99923616732282880 x + 3740744716124160 x^2 - 2794496983040 x^3 + 2257838080 x^4 + x^5;
coeff = Reverse@CoefficientList[eq, x];
{a, b} = {
    -451567616,
    solveResolvent[
        -203913591269621760,
        184161674750051152297984000,
        -124742258113864494225907240665088000,
        75106136945420552127297065232870932480000000,
        -58275659776 Sqrt[5],
        26315474732392120320 Sqrt[5]
    ]
}
x1 = N[Tr@Surd[b, 5] + a, 50]
First[x /. NSolve[eq == 0, WorkingPrecision -> 50]]
(*x1//RootReduce*)
RootApproximant[x1, 5]
```

After the verification of the numerical value, it is found that the fifty digits are exactly the same.

Comment: Nice. But I'd trust this more if it were verified to 1000 or so digits.