# Solving solvable quintics in trigonometric/radicals

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

If apply resultant to solvable quintic $f(x)$ as $Res_x(f(x),y+Rx+Sx^2+Tx^3)$ and associate output with trigonometric five-angle formula $\cos{5\theta} = 5cos{\theta} - 20cos^3{\theta} + 16cos^5{\theta}$, then get system of three equations over $\{R,S,T\}$, wich solvable in quadratic radicals (it is conjecture without any proof). And then source quintic is solvable in trigonometric function and radicals.

Code of this idea:

```
SolvingQuinticToTrigRad[Eq_] := {
   Print["\nEquation: 0 = ", Eq, "\n\nSolution by CAS:"];
   Print[x /. (Eq // NSolve) // Sort, "\n"];
   Print["Solution by formula:"];
   CL = CoefficientList[
     Collect[Resultant[Eq, y + R x + S x^2 + T x^3, x], y], y];
   Zz = CL[[5]]; Eo = CL[[6]];
   W = {-4 Dd^5 + 25 Cc Dd^3 Ee - 125 Bb Dd^2 Ee^2 + 625 Aa Dd Ee^3 - 
        3125 Ee^4 Ff,
       1 + 48 Dd^4 - 240 Cc Dd^2 Ee + 800 Bb Dd Ee^2 - 2000 Aa Ee^3,
       4 Dd^3 - 15 Cc Dd Ee + 25 Bb Ee^2, 1 - 8 Dd^2 + 20 Cc Ee}
      /. {Ff -> CL[[1]], Aa -> CL[[2]], Bb -> CL[[3]], Cc -> CL[[4]], 
       Dd -> CL[[5]], Ee -> CL[[6]]} // Factor;
   Q = Table[FactorList[W[[i]]][[2, 1]], {i, 4}];
   Vz = W[[1]];
   W = Resultant[{Q[[2]], Q[[3]]}, Q[[4]], R];
   U = Resultant[W[[1]], W[[2]], S] // Factor;(*Print[U];*)
   EqT = Select[FactorList[U], Exponent[#[[1]], T] == 4 &][[1, 1]];
   If[Exponent[EqT, T] == 4, lT = 4, 
    EqT = Select[FactorList[U], Exponent[#[[1]], T] == 2 &][[1, 1]]; 
    lT = 2];
   U = Resultant[W[[1]], W[[2]], T] // Factor;(*Print[U];*)
   EqS = Select[FactorList[U], Exponent[#[[1]], S] == 4 &][[1, 1]];
   If[Exponent[EqS, S] == 4, lS = 4, 
    EqS = Select[FactorList[U], Exponent[#[[1]], S] == 2 &][[1, 1]]; 
    lS = 2];
   W = Resultant[{Q[[2]], Q[[3]]}, Q[[4]], T];
   U = Resultant[W[[1]], W[[2]], S] // Factor;(*Print[U];Break[];*)
   EqR = Select[FactorList[U], Exponent[#[[1]], R] == 4 &][[1, 1]];
   If[Exponent[EqR, R] == 4, lR = 4, 
    EqR = Select[FactorList[U], Exponent[#[[1]], R] == 2 &][[1, 1]]; 
    lR = 2];
   (*{EqR,EqS,EqT}//Print;*)
   Rz = RootReduce[R /. Solve[EqR == 0, R]];
   Sz = RootReduce[S /. Solve[EqS == 0, S]];
   Tz = RootReduce[T /. Solve[EqT == 0, T]];
   X = {};
   Do[
    {Vo, Zo} = 
     RootReduce[{Vz, Zz} /. {R -> Rz[[i]], S -> Sz[[j]], 
        T -> Tz[[k]]}];
    Z = Table[Cos[(ArcCos[16 Vo] + 2 \[Pi] j)/5], {j, 0, 4}] // 
      Simplify;
    Y = (Z - Zo)/(5 Eo) // Simplify;
    X = Union[X, 
      x /. Solve[Y[[l]] + Rz[[i]] x + Sz[[j]] x^2 + Tz[[k]] x^3 == 0, 
        x, Cubics -> True]];
    X5 = {};
    Do[F = Eq /. x -> N[X[[i]], 32]; 
     If[Abs[Re[F]] < 10^-16 && Abs[Im[F]] < 10^-16, 
      X5 = Append[X5, X[[i]]]], {i, Length[X]}]
    , {l, 5}, {i, lR}, {j, lS}, {k, lT}
    ];
   Xt = {};
   Do[t = X5[[1]]; Xt = Append[Xt, t]; 
    X5 = DeleteCases[X5, x_ /; (x // N) == (t // N)], 4];
   Xt = Append[Xt, X5[[1]]]; X5 = Xt;
   X5 // N // Sort // Print;
   X5 // ToRadicals // Simplify // Print;
   };
```

Usage:

```
SolvingQuinticToTrigRad[12 - 5 x + x^5] // Timing
```

Some solvable quintics for verifing:

```
12 - 5 x + x^5
32 + 20 x + x^5
4 + x + 4 x^2 + 30 x^3 + x^5
979 + 2310 x - 55 x^2 - 110 x^3 + x^5
1 + 6 x - 12 x^2 - 32 x^3 + 16 x^4 + 32 x^5
2 - 5 x + 5 x^2 - 5 x^3 + 5 x^4 + 3 x^5
26 - 50 x + 50 x^2 - 50 x^3 + 50 x^4 + 15 x^5
9 - 10 x + 5 x^2 - 10 x^3 + 5 x^4 + 2 x^5
25 - 10 x + 2 x^2 - 9 x^3 + 2 x^4 + x^5
```

Please help to make this code more clear and fast and verify on other solvable quintics. How to do find of quadratic/biquadratic equations `EqR,EqS,EqT` without error messages?

Comment: I highly doubt the feasibility of this method, since it is likely that a quartic transformation is required to obtain the same solution equation.

Comment: @GalAster, only need solve quadratic and biquadratic equations `EqR,EqS,EqT` as factors of big polynomals `U`. It is surprising to me that these factors always exist for solvable quintics.

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to understand your code, but it's hard to debug with so many index operations.

I haven't fully understood it yet, so I'll give my solution first.

---

For the radical solution:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\\x_5 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ e^{+\frac{2 i \pi }{5}} & e^{+\frac{4 i \pi }{5}} & e^{-\frac{4 i \pi}{5}} & e^{-\frac{2 i \pi}{5}} \\ e^{+\frac{4 i \pi }{5}} & e^{-\frac{2 i \pi}{5}} & e^{+\frac{2 i \pi }{5}} & e^{-\frac{4 i \pi}{5}} \\ e^{-\frac{4 i \pi}{5}} & e^{+\frac{2 i \pi }{5}} & e^{-\frac{2 i \pi}{5}} & e^{+\frac{4 i \pi }{5}} \\ e^{-\frac{2 i \pi}{5}} & e^{-\frac{4 i \pi}{5}} & e^{+\frac{4 i \pi }{5}} & e^{+\frac{2 i \pi }{5}} \\ \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} \sqrt[5]{\zeta_1}\\ \sqrt[5]{\zeta_2}\\ \sqrt[5]{\zeta_3}\\ \sqrt[5]{\zeta_4}\\ \end{bmatrix}-\frac{b}{5a},
$$

can be rewritten in triangular form

$$
\begin{aligned}
x_{m,n}&=2 \sqrt[10]{\zeta _1 \zeta _2} \cos \left(\frac{1}{5} \arccos \left(\frac{\zeta _1+\zeta _2}{2 \sqrt{\zeta _1 \zeta _2}}\right)+\frac{2 \pi  m}{5}\right)\\
&+2 \sqrt[10]{\zeta _3 \zeta _4} \cos \left(\frac{1}{5} \arccos \left(\frac{\zeta _3+\zeta _4}{2 \sqrt{\zeta _3 \zeta _4}}\right)+\frac{2 \pi  n}{5}\right)\\
&-\frac{b}{5a}
\end{aligned}
$$

Because $\zeta_k$ is commutative, so $m, n$ depends on the choice of $\zeta_k$ order.

I don't know of any deterministic selection way, I use numerical calculations to determine the order.

```
trigSolve[z_, {x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_}, {m_, n_}] := Tr@{
    z,
    2 Sqrt[(x1 x2)^(1 / 5)] Cos[ArcCos[(x1 + x2) / (2 Sqrt[x1 x2])] / 5 + 2 Pi m / 5],
    2 Sqrt[(x3 x4)^(1 / 5)] Cos[ArcCos[(x3 + x4) / (2 Sqrt[x3 x4])] / 5 + 2 Pi n / 5]
};
```

---

For example solving $x^5 + x^4 - 4 x^3 - 3 x^2 + 3 x + 1 = 0$ with trigonometric.

Getting $\zeta_k$ with my code here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/268294/52360

```
eq = x^5 + x^4 - 4 x^3 - 3 x^2 + 3 x + 1;
{a, b} = {
    -(1 / 5),
    {
        Root[25937424601 + 492715403125 # + 4562314453125 #^2 + 29876708984375 #^3 + 95367431640625 #^4& , 1, 0],
        Root[25937424601 + 492715403125 # + 4562314453125 #^2 + 29876708984375 #^3 + 95367431640625 #^4& , 2, 0],
        Root[25937424601 + 492715403125 # + 4562314453125 #^2 + 29876708984375 #^3 + 95367431640625 #^4& , 3, 0],
        Root[25937424601 + 492715403125 # + 4562314453125 #^2 + 29876708984375 #^3 + 95367431640625 #^4& , 4, 0]
    }
};
nsol = x /. NSolve[eq == 0, x];
possible = Table[trigSolve[a, b, N@{i, j}], {i, 0, 4}, {j, 0, 4}];
order = FirstPosition[Chop[possible - #], 0] & /@ nsol - 1;
sol = trigSolve[a, b, #] & /@ order;
sol = sol // ToRadicals // Simplify
sol // N
nsol
```

So we got:

$$
\begin{aligned}
x_1=x_{3,2}=
&-\frac{2}{5} \sqrt{11} \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{5}-\frac{1}{5} \arccos\left(+\frac{25 }{44}\sqrt{\frac{5}{11}}-\frac{89}{44 \sqrt{11}}\right)\right)\\
&-\frac{2}{5} \sqrt{11} \cos \left(\frac{\pi }{5}+\frac{1}{5} \arccos\left(-\frac{25}{44} \sqrt{\frac{5}{11}}-\frac{89}{44 \sqrt{11}}\right)\right)\\
&-\frac{1}{5}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Also roots in radilcs can get from `Factor[x^5 + x^4 - 4 x^3 - 3 x^2 + 3 x + 1, 
 Extension -> Cos[1/5 ArcCos[(-89 + 25 Sqrt[5])/(44 Sqrt[11])]]]` or `Factor[x^5 + x^4 - 4 x^3 - 3 x^2 + 3 x + 1, 
 Extension -> Cos[1/5 ArcCos[1/22 Sqrt[1/22 (5523 - 2225 Sqrt[5])]]]]`